# Cannot click button - element not found

Tags: python, selenium, web

I have tried to make my script click the log in button on the [Spotify](https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fdk%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F) login page. I have been searching all day for a solution, but no matter what class, css or whatever I put in, it is just saying it could not find the object.

My code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?
continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fdk%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F") 
username = browser.find_element_by_id("login-username")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("login-password")
username.send_keys("myUser")
password.send_keys("myPass")
login = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ng-pristine ng-valid-sp-
disallow-chars ng-invalid ng-invalid-required').click()
```

It is the last line I have a problem with. Note: This is just one of the options I tried.

Comment: Not neccessarily related: The element with ``class="ng-pristine ng-valid-sp-disallow-chars ng-invalid ng-invalid-required"`` is the form, not the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code that have `xpath`:

```
login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Log In')]");
login.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(text(), 'Log In'])").click()
```

This should work so give it a try. :)

As @Verv stated, you could be having timing issues. So just for the test try with `time.sleep()` to see if this is it.

Comment: Got an error. "..Given xpath expression ".//button[text(), 'Log In']" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression."

Comment: sorry, I made syntax error, edited it and it should be fine now

Answer (score 0):

You're using multiple classes in your class selector. Try using only one class. Something like this:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn-green').click()
```

If it still doesn't work, perhaps the element has not yet been rendered when you try to click it, so you may want to try with an [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Also, I checked out your selector and it looks like you weren't even pointing to the button, but to the form.

And finally, a class selector may not be the optimal way to locate your element here. I'd probably go with a XPath selector to find the button that contains the text `Log In`, using the following XPath

```
//button[text()='Log In']
```

Comment: This one also works! Also thanks to you. Sadly i can not give 2 correct answers :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this, i Updated the answer:

```
login = browser.find_element_by_xapth("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-green ng-binding']")

login .click()
```

Comment: Getting an error - File "test.py", line 16
    login = browser.find_element_by_xapth('//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-green ng-binding']')
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax